# JNDI object with [java:jdbc/datasource] not found: JNDI implementation returned null- jboss with spring

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to use an existing jndi datasource in jboss server in my web application using spring. But I am getting JNDI object with [java:jdbc/datasource] not found: JNDI implementation returned null. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: could you please give us more details on this? The configuration you are using and how you are trying to get the datasource from spring project etc will help us to assist you.

Comment: Thanks for response. Im using jboss 4.3 and spring 4.0.3. My configuration is as below

Comment: jboss - web.xml                                                                          <resource-ref>
        <description>Database connection resource</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/datasource</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <jndi-name>java:jdbc/datasource</jndi-name>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>

Comment: Web.xml: <resource-ref>
    <description>Database connection resource</description>   
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/datasource</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>                                                                         Spring.xml:      <bean id="datasource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
  <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jndiTemplate" />
  <property name="jndiName" value="java:jdbc/datasource" />